# Anyone else having wrongly named boolean settings?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

It seems that when I use the boolean modifier it switches the resulting boolean option between difference and union.
This can't be normal right?

I'm using blnder 2.75
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain better? You ask to difference the 2 meshes in figure one and nothing happens?

Comment: Yes, I ask to difference but I get an output that is union. and vice versa.

Comment: Recalculate normals (Edit mode > select all > `Ctrl`+`N`). Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46399/boolean-does-not-slice-correctly-using-difference

Comment: It happens to me too. When I get the wrong boolean modifier and I can see it I just keep changing it until it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This can't be normal right?

Funny, it is because of *normal(s)*. Recalculate [surface normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in editmode. Also make sure the scale of the object is not negative (apply scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

Normals specify what is considered outside and what is considered inside of mesh. Booleans take this into account.

Comment: Would be useful if you mentioned how you can tell that normals need to be recalculated.

Comment: Thanks!
I feel kinda ashamed I dind't think of that. It didn't even occurred to me because I started out using basic shapes.

Comment: @RayMairlot You can tell it needed this by the dark purple/grey color of the mesh geometry.

Comment: @RayMairlot There is no specific way to tell - when you scale an object to negative values you won't see a shading difference. There are other situations when shading looks the same. You can tell by the booleans working weird - that's about it.

Comment: @Jerryno I was alluding to the fact that the shading of the objects in the screenshot were dark, indicating inverted normals. I just thought it might be useful to include that that can help deduce that normals are the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the example.

If you want to **difference** one mesh from another one like the example

[image]

Take 2 DIFFERENT MESH and in the first one select the modifier Boolean.

NB BEFORE DOING THAT REMEMBER TO CHECK (could be your problem) that both the meshes have faces not oriented inside. I.E Select first mesh - EDIT MODE - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
and then you can use the modfier right

press apply and you did it!

[image]